# Can I nest a <p> in a "small class" in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I've merged a bunch of HTML markup to get exactly what I'd like and it works great. However, I wonder if it is "correct"

Update: I don't think it is "correct" see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

So, to change my question slightly, I can just change my "p" tag to a "span" right? That should make it more correct.

I am referring to the nested paragraph tag that is within the "small class"

Here's the code:

```
<div class="card b-1 hover-shadow mb-20">
    <div class="media card-body">
        <div class="media-left pr-12">
            <img class="avatar avatar-xl no-radius" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="mb-2">
                <span class="fs-20 pr-16"> XHossein Shams</span>
            </div>
            <small class="fs-16 fw-300 ls-1">


                <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />

                <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span></p>

                <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>

            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right text-right d-none d-md-block">
            <p class="fs-14 text-fade mb-12"><i class="fa fa-map-marker pr-1"></i> Menlo Park, CA</p>
            <span class="text-fade"><i class="fa fa-money pr-1"></i> $60 per hour</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="card-footer flexbox align-items-center">
        <div>
            <strong>Cost of Tool:</strong>
            <span>Free &amp; Paid</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-hover-show">
            <a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-info" href="#">Tool Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-primary" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Am I correct in thinking that this line:

```
<small class="fs-16 fw-300 ls-1">
```

^^^ this is basically a "div" - is that correct?

Here's the CSS if it helps:

```
.pr-12 {
    padding-right: 12px !important;
}

.mb-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.b-1 {
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb !important;
}

.card {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.media {
    padding: 16px 12px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.media {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.card-body {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.media .avatar {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.no-radius {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.avatar-xl {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.avatar {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 36px;
    height: 36px; */
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f6f7;
    color: #8b95a5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
}

.mb-2 {
    margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
}

.fs-20 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.pr-16 {
    padding-right: 16px !important;
}

.ls-1 {
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}

.fw-300 {
    font-weight: 300 !important;
}

.fs-16 {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

.media-body>* {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

small, time, .small {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #8b95a5;
}

.fs-14 {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

.mb-12 {
    margin-bottom: 12px !important;
}

.text-fade {
    color: rgba(77,82,89,0.7) !important;
}

.card-footer:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-footer {
    background-color: #fcfdfe;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(77,82,89,0.07);
    color: #8b95a5;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-items-center {
    -ms-flex-align: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
}

.card-footer {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
/*

.card-footer {
    background-color: #fcfdfe;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.07);
    color: #8b95a5;
    padding: 10px 20px
} */

.card-footer>*:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.hover-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)
}

.fs-10 {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

Comment: ^ Thanks, I changed my question to reflect that.

Comment: I see nothing with a *small* class, only a `<small>` element. And no `<small>` is not basically a `<div>`, if anything it's closer to `span` but they are semantically different.

Comment: So no issues as I have it? The code works fine....

Comment: Have you tried [validating it](https://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input). `p` is not phrasing content and is not a valid child of `small`. It may work now, but there is no guarantee of it working in the future. Is what you've encapsulated in `small` really "side-comments and small print, like copyright and legal text, independent of its styled presentation", or would it be better off in another container, e.g `div`,`aside` or given there is form elements `fieldset`.

Comment: Correct @Jon P, it is not valid as a child element...

Comment: I just changed the "small" into a "div" and it works just as well...

Comment: small is an html5 element that looks to be an inline rather than block element, in fact small needs to go inside the paragraph and not outside it because of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small It's semantically incorrect to have inline elements enclose block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, sure. HTML is very flexible you can write a whole heap of invalid markup and seeming get away with it (for now). It doesn't mean you should.

You should write valid html as you have a stronger guarantee that it will/should work consistently now and in the future. You get no such guarantees with invalid code. You should also write semantically valid HTML as it gives a better hint as to the structure and intent of the document.

What you shouldn't do is choose tags/elements based on the default styling it gives you. The classic example is using `h3` when `h2` is the correct tag to use but a smaller font-size is required. Use the correct tag then style appropriately.

In your case [`aside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) seems like a good fit, but without knowing the full context of your document it's hard to tell.

```css
.pr-12 {
  padding-right: 12px !important;
}

.mb-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.b-1 {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb !important;
}

.card {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.media {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.media {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.media .avatar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.no-radius {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.avatar-xl {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 36px;
    height: 36px; */
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  color: #8b95a5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem!important;
}

.fs-20 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.pr-16 {
  padding-right: 16px !important;
}

.ls-1 {
  letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}

.fw-300 {
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}

.fs-16 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.media-body>* {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

small,
time,
aside,
.small {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #8b95a5;
}

.fs-14 {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.mb-12 {
  margin-bottom: 12px !important;
}

.text-fade {
  color: rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.7) !important;
}

.card-footer:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-footer {
  background-color: #fcfdfe;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.07);
  color: #8b95a5;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}


/*

.card-footer {
    background-color: #fcfdfe;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(77, 82, 89, 0.07);
    color: #8b95a5;
    padding: 10px 20px
} */

.card-footer>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.hover-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)
}

.fs-10 {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card b-1 hover-shadow mb-20">
  <div class="media card-body">
    <div class="media-left pr-12">
      <img class="avatar avatar-xl no-radius" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="mb-2">
        <span class="fs-20 pr-16"> XHossein Shams</span>
      </div>
      <aside class="fs-16 fw-300 ls-1">


        <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />

        <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span></p>

        <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>

      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="media-right text-right d-none d-md-block">
      <p class="fs-14 text-fade mb-12"><i class="fa fa-map-marker pr-1"></i> Menlo Park, CA</p>
      <span class="text-fade"><i class="fa fa-money pr-1"></i> $60 per hour</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="card-footer flexbox align-items-center">
    <div>
      <strong>Cost of Tool:</strong>
      <span>Free &amp; Paid</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-hover-show">
      <a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-info" href="#">Tool Home</a>
      <a class="btn btn-xs fs-10 btn-bold btn-primary" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```